# Submitting an Infopath form from a 2 page view - I get "The form cannot be submitted"

Tags: infopath

I have a page view that pulls in values. After it is submitted it then goes to another page view on the same form. I don't have any fields that repeat in the latter page view but when I click Submit I get this error:

```
The form cannot be submitted.
Save Conflict.
Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user.
If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.
```

But what I found is that if I closed the form ( instead of going to the next page view ), I can go to the intended subsequent page view; make the updates and Submit just fine.

I would much rather have the fluid flow from one page view to another but it seems I have to close the form first before updating anything on the next page view.

Is there a workaround to make it seamless ( "closing the form" being the clue ? ) Or better still fix the above error so that I can submit from the second page view as intended.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new form with two views each having just one text field. Create a button on view 1 with a rule to switch to view 2 when it is clicked. Create a button on view 2 to submit the data to a library. See if that works?

Comment: Hello Ahmad Zia thank you for your response. Forgive me but I do not follow. Please tell me how your example would help my form above?
and wouldn't the user have to click on 2 buttons now just to submit?

Comment: This is a test to make sure the infopath forms work as expected. Just conforming you already have 2 views with 1 button each? How you open the second view?